# Centered drawable stretched in Kitkat

Tags: android, android-drawable, xml-drawable

I have the following xml drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@android:color/white" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/previous_step" android:gravity="center"/>

</layer-list>
```

This is how it looks on Android 5:

[image]

However this is totall stretched in Android 4.4:

[image]

What can do to fix it on Android 4.4? Please note i can only use drawable xml, because this is the [background of the splash](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/splash-screens-the-right-way/).

Comment: Are you sure the same layout file is being loaded in both the cases?

Comment: @Shaishav yes, i am sure.

Comment: Show your xml then.

Comment: It is on the top of the question.

Comment: Did you fix this?